# How can I extract text from an HTML element containing a mix of `p` tags and inner text?

Tags: html, clojure, jsoup

I'm scraping a website with some poorly structured HTML using a Clojure wrapper around jsoup called [Reaver](https://github.com/mischov/reaver). Here is an example of some of the HTML structure:

```
<div id="article">
  <aside>unwanted text</aside>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <nav><ol><li><h2>unwanted text</h2></li></ol></nav>
  <p>More text</p>
  <h2>A headline</h2>
  <figure><figcaption>unwanted text</figcaption></figure>
  <p>More text</p>
  Here is a paragraph made of some raw text directly in the div
  <p>Another paragraph of text</p>
  More raw text and this one has an <a>anchor tag</a> inside
  <dl>
    <dd>unwanted text</dd>
  </dl>
  <p>Etc etc</p>
</div>
```

This `div` represents an article on a wiki. I want to extract the text from it, but as you can see, some paragraphs are in `p` tags, and some are contained directly within the div. I also need the headlines and anchor tag text.

I know how to parse and extract the text from all of the `p`, `a`, and `h` tags, and I can select for the `div` and extract the inner text from it, but the problem is that I end up with two selections of text that I need to merge somehow.

How can I extract the text from this div, so that all of the text from the `p`, `a`, `h` tags, as well as the inner text on the `div`, are extracted in order? The result should be paragraphs of text in the same order as what is in the HTML.

Here is what I am currently using to extract, but the inner `div` text is missing from the results:

```
(defn get-texts [url]
  (:paragraphs (extract (parse (slurp url))
                        [:paragraphs]
                        "#article > *:not(aside, nav, table, figure, dl)" text)))
```

Note also that additional unwanted elements appear in this `div`, e.g., `aside`, `figure`, etc. These elements contain text, as well as nested elements with text, that should not be included in the result.

Comment: What happens if you change "#article > *:not(aside, nav, table, figure, dl)" to "#article, #article > *:not(aside, nav, table, figure, dl)" or "#article *:not(aside, nav, table, figure, dl)"?

Comment: Another approach would be to use Hickory (https://github.com/davidsantiago/hickory) to parse the page into hiccup-notation (or some other format). Then you can use clojure.spec to make sense of that data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extract the entire article as a JSoup object (likely an `Element`), then convert it to an EDN representation using `reaver/to-edn`.  Then you go through the `:content` of that and handle both strings (the result of `TextNode`s) and elements that have a `:tag` that interests you.

(Code by vaer-k)

```clj
(defn get-article [url]
  (:article (extract (parse (slurp url))
                     [:article]
                     "#article"
                     edn)))

(defn text-elem?
  [element]
  (or (string? element)
      (contains? #{:p :a :b :i} (:tag element))))

(defn extract-text
  [{content :content}]
  (let [text-children (filter text-elem? content)]
    (reduce #(if (string? %2)
               (str %1 %2)
               (str %1 (extract-text %2)))
            ""
            text-children)))

(defn extract-article [url]
  (-> url
      get-article
      extract-text))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using the `tupelo.forest` library, which was presented in an "Unsession" of the Clojure/Conj 2019 just last week.

Below is the solution written as a unit test.  First some declarations and the sample data:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.forest tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [schema.core :as s]
    [tupelo.string :as ts]))

(def html-src
  "<div id=\"article\">
    <aside>unwanted text</aside>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <nav><ol><li><h2>unwanted text</h2></li></ol></nav>
    <p>More text</p>
    <h2>A headline</h2>
    <figure><figcaption>unwanted text</figcaption></figure>
    <p>More text</p>
    Here is a paragraph made of some raw text directly in the div
    <p>Another paragraph of text</p>
    More raw text and this one has an <a>anchor tag</a> inside
    <dl>
    <dd>unwanted text</dd>
    </dl>
    <p>Etc etc</p>
  </div> ")
```

To start off, we add the html data (a tree) to the forest after removing all newlines, etc.  This uses [the Java "TagSoup" parser](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.171/api/tupelo.parse.tagsoup) internally:

```
(dotest
  (hid-count-reset)
  (with-forest (new-forest)
    (let [root-hid            (add-tree-html
                                (ts/collapse-whitespace html-src))
          unwanted-node-paths (find-paths-with root-hid [:** :*]
                                (s/fn [path :- [HID]]
                                  (let [hid  (last path)
                                        node (hid->node hid)
                                        tag  (grab :tag node)]
                                    (or
                                      (= tag :aside)
                                      (= tag :nav)
                                      (= tag :figure)
                                      (= tag :dl)))))]
      (newline) (spyx-pretty :html-orig (hid->bush root-hid))
```

The `spyx-pretty` shows the "bush" format of the data (similar to hiccup format):

```
:html-orig (hid->bush root-hid) =>
[{:tag :html}
 [{:tag :body}
  [{:id "article", :tag :div}
   [{:tag :aside, :value "unwanted text"}]
   [{:tag :p, :value "Some text"}]
   [{:tag :nav}
    [{:tag :ol} [{:tag :li} [{:tag :h2, :value "unwanted text"}]]]]
   [{:tag :p, :value "More text"}]
   [{:tag :h2, :value "A headline"}]
   [{:tag :figure} [{:tag :figcaption, :value "unwanted text"}]]
   [{:tag :p, :value "More text"}]
   [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw,
     :value
     " Here is a paragraph made of some raw text directly in the div "}]
   [{:tag :p, :value "Another paragraph of text"}]
   [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw,
     :value " More raw text and this one has an "}]
   [{:tag :a, :value "anchor tag"}]
   [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw, :value " inside "}]
   [{:tag :dl} [{:tag :dd, :value "unwanted text"}]]
   [{:tag :p, :value "Etc etc"}]]]]
```

So we can see the data has been loaded correctly. Now, we want to remove all of the unwanted nodes as identified by the `find-paths-with`.  Then, print the modified tree:

```
      (doseq [path unwanted-node-paths]
        (remove-path-subtree path))
      (newline) (spyx-pretty :html-cleaned (hid->bush root-hid))

:html-cleaned (hid->bush root-hid) =>
[{:tag :html}
 [{:tag :body}
  [{:id "article", :tag :div}
   [{:tag :p, :value "Some text"}]
   [{:tag :p, :value "More text"}]
   [{:tag :h2, :value "A headline"}]
   [{:tag :p, :value "More text"}]
   [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw,
     :value
     " Here is a paragraph made of some raw text directly in the div "}]
   [{:tag :p, :value "Another paragraph of text"}]
   [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw,
     :value " More raw text and this one has an "}]
   [{:tag :a, :value "anchor tag"}]
   [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw, :value " inside "}]
   [{:tag :p, :value "Etc etc"}]]]]
```

At this point, we simply walk the tree and accumulate any surviving text nodes into a vector:

```
      (let [txt-accum (atom [])]
        (walk-tree root-hid
          {:enter (fn [path]
                    (let [hid   (last path)
                          node  (hid->node hid)
                          value (:value node)] ; may not be present
                      (when (string? value)
                        (swap! txt-accum append value))))})
```

To verify, we compare the found text nodes (ignoring whitespace) to the desired result:

```
        (is-nonblank=  (str/join \space @txt-accum)
          "Some text
           More text
           A headline
           More text
           Here is a paragraph made of some raw text directly in the div
           Another paragraph of text
           More raw text and this one has an
           anchor tag
            inside
           Etc etc")))))
```

For more details, see [the README file](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.171/doc/tupelo-forest-one-tree-to-rule-them-all) and [the API docs](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.171/api/tupelo.forest).  Be sure to also view [the Lightning Talk](https://youtu.be/RtavTnRr0oM) for an overview.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed solution and explanation. I think many people will find it helpful in the future. Because it introduces a new library with its own large set of unique semantics and idioms, I find it too heavy for my problem, and prefer to simply perform some simple filters on an edn representation of the html.